# execution of php webservice at a given time dynamically using cron job and without using cpanel in the live server

Tags: php, cron

I have the given php code :

```
<?php
require 'dbconnect.php';
$sql="INSERT INTO `notifications` (`username`, `password`) VALUES ('lalith', 'kumar');";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
if($res)
{
    $id=mysql_insert_id();
    $message=array("message"=>"successfully inserted","id"=>$id);
}
else
{
    $message=array("message"=>"insertion failed".mysql_error());
}
echo json_encode($message);
?>
```

which i want to execute at a particular time dynamically using corn job in the live server having no cpanel or any other panel..  Can any one tell me how to solve this problem

Comment: what time you need to run it at

Comment: ssh to the server, do `crontab -e` and give it yout command line google cron job php script.  Also no point in echoing out anything from your cron as its headless unless you're going to log it to a text file of some description

Comment: Is this a server you are hosting yourself or a server hosted by someone else? If the latter do you have any sort of SSH access?

Comment: he said dynamically so the crontab needs to be edited via some sort of a web app i think

Comment: not really possible without unsecuring the server as the web app would need to write  to /etc/crontab/user/crontab etc which kinda is possible via exec() but really.... ?

Comment: can you explain in detail@Dave

Comment: Not sure that i understand 'dynamically' (?) part, but this could (maybe) help: https://www.setcronjob.com/ ?

Comment: Dynamically means execute the particular php file at a given time without any manual interaction@nevermind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused in what you are asking here.  Do you want to run the cron job on the same server that the script lives on?  If so then it is not really a web service and echoing output will do nothing.

You may want to run a cronjob on another box, that calls this script on a regular basis.  Fine, and doable but you have another step in there.  You will need something (like a script or app) that can call the web service and consume the output and process it accordingly.

To just run this php script, go to the servers command line:

```
crontab -e * 2 * * * <path to php>/php <path to script>/runme.php
```

Make sure you have permissions to see and execute the files in question otherwise this will fail.  The command above will execute every day at 2am.  See the following site for a reference on how to change your time:
http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference/

Based upon the comment below the path to the script will be something like:

```
/var/www/html/push/add.php
```

Comment: what i have to give in the place of path to php and path to script in the command line, beacuse my file is located at http://www.doreg.com/push/add.php

Comment: path to php will be something like /usr/sbin/php  you may also want to run it with the switch -q instead

Comment: if path to script will be /var/www/html/push/add.php, then what will be the path to php